# Speed of light in straight vs. circular optical fiber

Tags: speed-of-light, fiber-optics

What is the comparison of speed of light in an optical fiber when it is stretched in a straight line vs. when it is bent in a circle? Please provide computation or reference.

I think the bent fiber transmit light slower. In a straight fiber, the light is allowed to travel in a straight line together with other zig-zag paths. In a bent fiber, the straightest line it can travel is constrained by the inner and out radii of the curvature of the bend. The ratio of distance traveled or time taken on straight over circular path is $q=\frac1{2\sqrt d}\arccos\frac{1-d}{1+d}$ where $d$ is the ratio of the radius of the core fiber over the radius of the curvature of the central axis. For $d\in(0,1]$, $q<1$ because 
$$a)\quad \tan\sqrt d-\sqrt d=\int_0^\sqrt d \big((\sec x)^2-1\big)dx>0 \Longleftrightarrow\frac1{\sqrt{1+d}}>\cos\sqrt d\Longleftrightarrow\frac{1-d}{1+d}>2(\cos\sqrt d)^2-1=\cos2\sqrt d,$$
or
$$b)\quad f(d):=\arccos\frac{1-d}{1+d}-2\sqrt d=\int_0^d f'(x)dx =-\int_0^d\frac{\sqrt x}{1+x}dx<0,$$
The shortest path in the circular fiber is longer than that in the straight one.

But this is a rough estimate, as I assume the straight line fiber is equivalent to having the light traveling in the center line in the bent fiber, and I am assuming the wavelength of the light is much smaller than the core radius of the fiber so that the light can be treated as a ray. A more rigorous analysis would give a more accurate answer. Surely the fully rigorous one would call for Maxwell wave equations in a circular waveguide. Is there a simple approximation in between that will give a good result?

Comment: Just curious: why do you expect it to differ?

Comment: @Asher: The (total internal) reflection paths and therefore the distance of the light traveled in the circular fiber are different from the straight fiber.

Comment: do you mean cross-section of the fiber? then it is not "straight" but "rectangular"

Comment: @aaaaaa: No, not cross section. I have rephrased the question. Let me know whether it is clear now.

Comment: Typical optical fiber can't be bent into a diameter smaller than about 4 cm without damage. That gives a ratio of over 4 million between the core diameter and the bend diameter. Do you still expect it to affect the propagation velocity significantly?

Comment: @photon should know. OP, you also should write what you have come up with

Comment: @ThePhoton: I just added a rough estimate in my question. With your number for maximal bend, the light in the circular fiber takes $10^{-6}$ longer in ratio.

Comment: 1. That's probably less than the effect of the stress induced change in the refractive index. 2. You can't really use ray optics to analyze this situation, you have to use wave optics.

Comment: @ThePhoton: I agree. I said the same as your second comment in my edition of the question. However, the fully rigorous treatment would call for the Maxwell equations for waveguide. Is it really necessary? I do not know how short the typical wave length of the light is compared to the core radius of the fiber.

Comment: @Hans, I was assuming you were asking about single-mode fiber. Typical core diameter 9 um; typical wavelength 1.3-1.6 um. Typical multimode fibers have 50, 62.5 or 100 or 1000 um core diameter, and is used with wavelengths from 650 to 980 nm. Often the index profile is parabolic rather than step shaped, which complicates the analysis. When detecting bending in fiber optic sensors, it is more common to detect birefringence (difference in index for different polarizations) than the raw change in propagation delay.

Comment: Note also that for large core-diameter step-index fibers, the only type where ray  optics is sensible, not all of the signal will propagate "nearly along the axis". Some will be nearly along the axis, but some of the signal will be on rays with greater or lesser angle to the axis. This is the dominant source of dispersion in these fibers (meaning some signal energy takes longer to travel along the fiber than other energy, spreading any input pulse applied), and is again probably a larger effect than the change in delay due to bending the fiber.

Comment: @ThePhoton: In conclusion, are you saying there is no significant effect on (presumably slowing down) the speed of the light due to bending the fiber?

Comment: Yes. Any effect there is, is much smaller than other effects that would be present in a tightly bent fiber.